# "Start" command not working while running a batch file

Tags: batch-file, asynchronous, command-line

I am creating a batch file which loads some applications back to back. However, one of the applications has to run asynchronously, because it essentially launches the window and then never returns the control. I was looking for a command which lets me run the application in asynchronous async manner, and I came across the [START](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command.

However, I can launch the application when I do not use the start command. Whenever, I use the start command nothing happens. There are no errors, but it just does not launch the application. I also tried `/b` and `/wait` options, but no help.

My command is as the following:

```
start C:\Users\c_desaik\Desktop\Queueingsystem\Upload System.exe
```

One more thing that I realized is that start command works if the path of executable is not wrapped in quotes. I am not sure why is this a problem. This means that if I change the command above to

```
start C:\Users\c_desaik\Desktop\Queueingsystem\Trial.exe (No spaces in the path)
```

It does work. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I updated my question with more modifications

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Start` command requires as first parameter the window title as in `Start /?`

> START ["title"] [/D path] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED]
>         [/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL]...

So, try the following:

`start "" "path\to\your\executable"`

Comment: Your answer is correct, but just slightly incorrect (if that makes sense). The `title` parameter is not required, however the first quoted string that `START` finds is treated as the title.

Comment: Exactly, if we try to run `start some\path\without\spaces` it works fine.